# Vuex - Efficiently sharing an Array across components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue.js app. In this app, I have an array of items that I want to use in multiple single file components. This array may be fairly large. For that reason, I'm trying to reduce instances of the array in memory.

Since I intend to share this array across components, I thought a centralized store made sense. For this reason, I started to integrate [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

In my app, I have the following:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    contacts: [
      // large number of JSON objects here.
    ]
  }
}); 

const app = new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#myApp',    
    data: {},

    created: function() {
    }
});
```

I have a single file component that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        <thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="contact in contacts">
            <td>{{ contact.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.lastName }} </td>
            <td>{{ contact.email }} </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {};
        }
    };
</script>
```

In reality, I have multiple single file components that will need to use `contacts` from the `store`. However, I'm not sure what the most efficient way to use them in each component. Since each component has it's own isolated scope, it seems like if I use the `props` or `data` options, I'd be recreating my `contacts` Array for each component. This seems expensive. Or, I'm misunderstanding something.

What is the most efficient way to share an Array with multiple components when I already have defined it in a central data store?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach is to use the [`mapState` helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) in your component. For example

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex' 
export default {
  computed: mapState(['contacts'])
}
```

This will map the `contacts` state in your store into a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) `contacts` in your component.

Comment: It took a minute for it to click with me. You responded before I could delete my comment :). Thanks four fast response.

Comment: @ZachTempleton no problem. The documentation also shows you how to mix `mapState` and other Vuex helpers with your own computed properties via the spread-operator

Answer (score 0):

Vuex effectively shares only one instance of the state across multiple components (it is a single source of truth in the app). So you shouldn't be concerned about performance in this case. Vue is also very clever in the way it handles changes, recreating only the component parts that actually changed. Just go for it, you will never regret starting with Vuex.